# How to draw gradient arc using d3.js?

Tags: javascript, css, html, d3.js, svg

I have started using [d3.js](http://d3js.org/). I have following requirement

#### Requirement:

[image]

#### What I have tried?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BTfmH/234/)

#### Question?

How to achieve gradient as same as above image.

Any suggestion or idea will be grateful.

#### Note

I am just started `d3.js`.

Comment: Maybe if you gaussian blur the stroke at the edge of the arc, that would do it.

Comment: You'll probably be using d3.arc, which has a specified start and end angle. So all you have to do is break each segment up into many smaller parts and apply the gradient to it (either via array or using a d3 scale). You could also simply create a pie chart of 100 arcs and color each individually based on the percentage.

Comment: i believe, i've managed to do a gradient on the white background arc http://jsfiddle.net/BTfmH/242/, although i'm not sure how it works. In fact it's a radial gradient but it works fine on a circle with linearGradient coordinates - x1,y1...not with cx,cy,r... Strange.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Edit - changed data structure and fiddle link to represent unfilled chunk at the beginning.

I would use the pie function in d3 to create a pie chart.
The image above is basically a pie with two different gradient styles applied to the pie chunks. 
A red linear gradient and a black/white radial gradient.

I created a fiddle linked below to show you an example. 
The key here is that you need to structure your data to also include the percentage that should not have the red-gradient applied.
Using the example above, we have three chunks with red and the rest as unfilled. 
Imagine the data set like so:

```
    var data = [{
    percent: 10,
    pie: 0
}, {
    percent: 13,
    pie: 1
}, {
    percent: 13,
    pie: 1
}, {
    percent: 6,
    pie: 1
}, {
    percent: 56,
    pie: 0
}];
```

So we have the percent and we also flag which chunks should be red and which chunk should be the unfilled section using the pie attribute.

You can use whatever data set you wish but I'm just using this as an example.

So next thing is to create your SVG element:

```
 var width = 400;
    var height = 400;
    var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
     .outerRadius(radius - 10)
     .innerRadius(((radius - 10) / 5) * 4);


    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function (d) { return d.percent });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");
```

and after this we will create the two gradients to style the pie chunks. 
So first one is the linear red gradient:

```
// append a defs tag to SVG, This holds all our gradients and can be used
//by any element within the SVG we append it to
var defs = svg.append("svg:defs")

//next we append a linear gradient 
var red_gradient = defs.append("svg:linearGradient")
  .attr("id", "gradient")
  .attr("x1", "0%")
  .attr("y1", "0%")
  .attr("x2", "0%")
  .attr("y2", "100%")
  .attr("spreadMethod", "pad");

//first dark red color
    red_gradient.append("svg:stop")
        .attr("offset", "0%")
        .attr("stop-color", "rgb(221,48,2)")
        .attr("stop-opacity", 1);
//second light red color
    red_gradient.append("svg:stop")
        .attr("offset", "100%")
        .attr("stop-color", "rgb(247, 78, 1)")
        .attr("stop-opacity", 1);
```

Then we append the radial gradient for the unfilled part. This one is a little tricker because we need to move the gradient with a transform to get the right radial center. If you translate it half the width and height I think it should work out.

```
var radial_gradient = defs.append("radialGradient")
.attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
.attr("cx", '50%')
.attr("cy", '50%')
.attr("r", "75%")
.attr("fx", '50%')
.attr("fy", '50%')
.attr('gradientTransform', "translate(-200,-200)")
.attr("id", 'gradient2');
 radial_gradient.append("stop").attr("offset", "0%").style("stop-color", "black");
 radial_gradient.append("stop").attr("offset", "55%").style("stop-color", "white");
 radial_gradient.append("stop").attr("offset", "95%").style("stop-color", "black");
```

Once we have set up the gradients, we can add the pie:

```
   var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
     .data(pie(data))
     .enter().append("g")
     .attr("class", "arc");

    // we create a function to append the different chucks of the pie. 
    // we check the pie attribute from the data and apply the correct gradient.

    g.append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .style("fill", function (d) {
        if (d.data.pie === 1) {
            console.log('true' + d.data.pie);
            return "url(#gradient)"
        }
        else {
            console.log('false' + d.data.pie);
            return "url(#gradient2)"
        }
    })
```

JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/staceyburnsy/afo292ty/2/

Comment: No probs, let me know if you get stuck with the circles or animation

Comment: Actually it should be responsive. Anyways thanks a lot

Comment: Don't think it would be a big deal to change the hard coded values to dynamic based on parent width/height. The gradients and the svg objects can be targeted by their id's/classes on window load and resize